# Why These two c# scripts give different results?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a big list of buttons and trying to `AddListener()` for every Button on this list using a quick way

the first way is

```
btn[0] = CHbutt[0].GetComponent<Button>(); btn[0].onClick.AddListener(delegate { CH(0); });
btn[1] = CHbutt[1].GetComponent<Button>(); btn[1].onClick.AddListener(delegate { CH(1); });
btn[2] = CHbutt[2].GetComponent<Button>(); btn[2].onClick.AddListener(delegate { CH(2); });
btn[3] = CHbutt[3].GetComponent<Button>(); btn[3].onClick.AddListener(delegate { CH(3); });
```

and it works very well, and `AddListener()` to all Buttons in `btn[]`;
but a lot of lines...

the second way

```
for (int i = 0; i < CHmatt.Count; i++)
{
    btn[i] = CHbutt[i].GetComponent<Button>(); btn[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate { CH(i); });
}
```

but this one is not working, this one `AddListener()` to only the last button `btn[0]`

I'm very curious about the difference between these two scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a capturing issue. Change the code as follows, to avoid capturing `i`:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < CHmatt.Count; i++)
{
    var ii = i;
    btn[i] = CHbutt[i].GetComponent<Button>(); 
    btn[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate { CH(ii); });
}
```

What is being passed into `AddListener` function is a `delegate` method; however, since you're passing in a loop iteration variable `i`, the *context is captured*, and `i` is actually referenced. As your loop advances, the value of `i` changes for *all captures*, therefore making this approach "not work".

By introducing a local copy of `i` (the name is not material here, I called it `ii`), which goes out of scope on each loop iteration, the capture of `i` is avoided, and the actual value of `ii` is passed to the `delegate` method (technically, captured, but it's a copy of `i` for each loop iteration, and therefore does not change as `i` changes.)

Comment: @CoolBots - Much nicer. :-)